# Zoom bar disfigured in Google-Maps-for-Rails (gmaps4rails)

Tags: google-maps, gmaps4rails

For some reason my zoom bar is all pixelated and I'm not sure why. Any ideas? I used the basic setup:

```
Controller: @json = User.all.to_gmaps4rails
View: <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

I'm not passing any special parameters or anything. The markers that I have on my models show up beautifully.

[image: Zoom broken]

Comment: Must be a CSS-issue, I guess some global CSS is affecting the control.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add this to your css... there you will also have an issue with the terrain and overlays dropdowns...

```
#mapCanvas label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#mapCanvas img { max-width: none; }
```

Comment: Just noting that this is an issue because of bootstrap

Answer (score 11):

With the gmaps4rails 1.5.6, use **map** instead of **mapCanvas**, i.e.,

```
#map label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map img { max-width: none; }
```

Reference:

Github: twitter/bootstrap issue list - Bootstrap distorts some Google Maps Controls and Overlays - commented by diogocsc
 
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1552#issuecomment-11153057

Answer (score 1):

This what I found and the solutions is simple.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1552

Comment: [answer] - "Provide context for links"