# google maps api v3 map display issue

Tags: google-maps-api-3

look at the map on this page: http://demo.wpconsult.net/sample/sub-page-11
if you select the location in the left pane next to the map, the infobubble pops up but it looks broken. 
I wonder if it's related to the Mime type warnings in google chrome inspector?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Zoom bar disfigured in Google-Maps-for-Rails (gmaps4rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548330/zoom-bar-disfigured-in-google-maps-for-rails-gmaps4rails)

Add these to your css. (another source I found recommended removing the `img { max-width }` if there was one.)

```
#map-canvas label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map-canvas img { max-width: none; }
```

p.s. I think everyone gets the mime-type warnings.

Comment: thanks mate! I had just found that other solution that works, but I like yours better :)

Comment: Not really my solution, I just happened to see the same situation one or two days ago. Glad to help :)