# Google maps overlay rendering issue

Tags: google-maps

[image: notice the way the tooltip is rendering]

For some strange reason google maps tends to load the tooltip like that. Also the zoom slider is skewed as well. Has anyone run into this problem before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely seen it before :)

[google maps api v3 map display issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466737/google-maps-api-v3-map-display-issue/10466752)

Add to your CSS

```
#map_canvas label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map_canvas img { max-width: none; }  (sometimes max-height: none; is needed too)
```

(replacing `map_canvas` if your map div is named something else.)

Comment: You're welcome! I spend way too much time following this tag :D

Comment: Although SO doesn't want me to say thanks and +1, I believe its the appropriate thing to say right now. Thanks, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. And this worked for me.

```
#map_canvas label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map_canvas img { max-width: none; max-height: none; background-color: transparent;}
```