# google maps bad resolution and small marker looking

Tags: google-maps

I have a problem with google maps that the resolution of the map is strangely appearing and the marker is so small.

Any solution to this problem ?

[image]

Comment: i found the solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745847/google-maps-overlay-rendering-issue

Answer (score 1):

you must adjust zoom. I can help you with the marker if I view the code