# Google Maps API V3 Controls and Info Windows look weird

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to teach myself Google Maps API V3 and I'm stuck.

The default zoom controls are squashed. The info boxes have some stuff on the button and the close button is whited out.

Can you please look at my page: http://f1racingclutchsystem.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=6

Is it possible that some of the styles on the webpage are causing this?

Comment: To let you know, on nexus 4 chrome there aren't any other controls except map/satellite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps api v3 map display issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466737/google-maps-api-v3-map-display-issue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 : weird UI display glitches (with screenshot)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471830/google-maps-api-v3-weird-ui-display-glitches-with-screenshot/7623351#7623351)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your CSS. This same conflict happens when there are maps on sites that use Twitter Bootstrap.

In your case, this file `catalog/view/theme/yooresponsive/stylesheet/responsive.css`